# How Java awt/swing knows what UI element i clicked?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I think Java recive like an Event from Windows with the coordinate of the pointer, does Java loop through every UI element and check its coordinate to fire the Event?

Comment: *does Java loop through every UI element and check its coordinate* - basically, yes. Why do you need to know?

Answer (score 0):

If you want details about the implementation, you can check out the source code (Java is open source) on GitHub: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk